# make a field mandatory using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a select field mandatory on a web page. I know how to do it with help of JS and form attribute 'onsubmit' and returning the function. But the problem is that form code is already written and I dont know how to add attribute now. Let me know if I can append attribute dynamically from JS. 
The other way I tried is to call the JS after page loaded. But this isnt making the field mandatory and form can be submitted.
Following is my code..

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <script>
       function f1()
       {
           var countryValue = document.getElementById('count ID').value;

    if (countryValue == "") 
    {
            alert("field value missing");
        return false;
    }
    var stateValue = document.getElementById('state ID').value;
    if (stateValue == "") 
    {
            alert("state field value missing");
        return false;
    }
}

      </script>
     </head>
     <body>
    <form method = "post" action = "33.html">
    Country: <input type="text" id="count ID">
    state: <select id="state ID"> 
             <option></option>
                     <option value="ap">ap</option> 
                     <option value="bp">bp</option> 
                    </select>
    <br>
    <input type = "submit">
    </form>
    <script>window.onload=f1</script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Please help.

Comment: if (thereIsAnError()) {myButton.disabled=true}

Comment: you have space on your id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this since you have messed up the IDs

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/nMzUe/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.forms[0].onsubmit=function() { // first form on page
    var countryValue = this.elements[0].value; // first field in form
    if (countryValue == "") {
      alert("Please enter a country");
      return false;
    }
    var stateIdx = this.elements[1].selectedIndex; // second field
    if (stateIdx < 1) { // your first option does not have a value 
      alert("Please select a state");
      return false;
    }
    return true; // allow submission
  }
}
```

PS: It is likely that POSTing to an html page will give you an error

To get the last button to do the submission

```
window.onload=function() {
  var form = document.forms[0]; // first form
  // last element in form:
  form.elements[form.elements.length-1].onclick=function() { 
  ...
  ...
  ...
   this.form.submit(); // instead of return true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful. Now that my form doesnt have submit btn, instead its validated by <input type="button" id="save" onclick=".."> 
In this case, how to call the JS function?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got a function to detect improper values (empty mandatory field or anything else, like a bad e-mail address for instance) you have a few different options :

- disable the submit button
- cancel the onclick event on the button
- cancel the submit event on the form

disabling the submit button can be annoying for the user (it might flash on and off while the values are entered).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but i made a extension. Using hook system to translate fields with "*", in the names, to validate like required field. This is a simple solution not intrusive where is not required addition of fields in the database, only by the use of sufix "*" in configuration of custom fields.

There is the code: https://github.com/voiski/bugzilla-required-field